# xampp issue port 80 or 8080 doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, port

I have installed XAMPP on windows 7 and tryed to start the Apache and MySQL server. It hasn't worked. Then I tried to change the port listen 80 to listen 8080 by clicking Config on the same line as Apache and choosing httpd.config but even that won't work.

When I start Apache and MySQL it says in the console that:

```
15:33:34  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
15:33:34  [main]    Windows Version: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
15:33:34  [main]    XAMPP Version: 5.6.11
15:33:34  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
15:33:34  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
15:33:34  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
15:33:34  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
15:33:34  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
15:33:34  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "d:\xampp\"
15:33:34  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
15:33:34  [main]    All prerequisites found
15:33:34  [main]    Initializing Modules
15:33:34  [Apache]  Problem detected!
15:33:34  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 5028!
15:33:34  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:33:34  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:33:34  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:33:34  [Apache]  Problem detected!
15:33:34  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 5028!
15:33:34  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:33:34  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:33:34  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:33:34  [mysql]   MySQL Service detected with wrong path
15:33:34  [mysql]   Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
15:33:34  [mysql]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
15:33:34  [mysql]   Found Path: "D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
15:33:34  [mysql]   Expected Path: d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=d:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
15:33:34  [mysql]   Problem detected!
15:33:34  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
15:33:34  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:33:34  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:33:34  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:33:34  [main]    The Mercury module is disabled
15:33:34  [main]    The Tomcat module is disabled
15:33:34  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
15:33:34  [main]    Control Panel Ready
15:36:36  [Apache]  Problem detected!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 5028!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:36:36  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:36:36  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:36:36  [Apache]  Problem detected!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 5028!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:36:36  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:36:36  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:36:36  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
15:36:36  [Apache]  Problem detected!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 5028!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:36:36  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:36:36  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:36:36  [Apache]  Problem detected!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 5028!
15:36:36  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:36:36  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:36:36  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:36:36  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
15:36:36  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
15:36:37  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
15:36:37  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
15:36:37  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
15:36:37  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
15:36:37  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
15:36:37  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
15:36:37  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
15:36:37  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
15:36:38  [mysql]   Problem detected!
15:36:38  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
15:36:38  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
15:36:38  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
15:36:38  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
15:36:38  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

**What should I do?**

Comment: after changing port from 80 to 8080, restart your apache service.

Comment: `Port 80 in use by "D:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"` ... did you try to quit skype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it doesn't seem like you are actually using port 8080. Apache tries to use the ports 80 and 443, which are already blocked by Skype.

And whatever that is `""D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"`, it blocks your port 3306 for mysql.

You should either kill those processes or change the ports for Apache and MySql again. For Apache use the "config" button and than edit the `httpd.conf` file. In that file change the line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`. After that make sure that you save your changes.

Same for MySql and port 3306 if you want to use it (here it is `my.ini`).